# php- retrive table header in modal form

Tags: php

I have a booking system and I want help in applying my idea. as you can see here is the table for booking. when the user picks a room from the checkbox and picks a time and presses submit. in the modal, I want to fill the timeslot field and the room by the choices he chooses.

**Here is the booking table**
[image]

**And here is the Modal**
[image: And here is the Modal]

Here is my code

**php**

```
function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end){
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $interval = new DateInterval("PT".$duration."M");
    $cleanupInterval = new DateInterval("PT".$cleanup."M");
    $slots = array();
    
    for($intStart = $start; $intStart<$end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupInterval)){
        $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        $endPeriod->add($interval);
        if($endPeriod>$end){
            break;
        }
        
        $slots[] = $intStart->format("H:iA")." - ". $endPeriod->format("H:iA");
        
    }
    
    return $slots;
}


function build_calendar($month, $year) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'pmudb');
    /*$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from bookings where MONTH(date) = ? AND YEAR(date)=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $month, $year);
    $bookings = array();
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $bookings[] = $row['date'];
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }*/
   
    $calendar = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    $calendar .= "<center><h2>test</h2>";

    
    $calendar .= " 
    <tr>";

    $duration = 60;
$cleanup = 0;
$start = "08:00";
$end = "17:00";
$timeslots = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
 $calendar .= "<th  class='header'>Room#</th>";
    // Create the calendar headers
    foreach($timeslots  as $day) {
        $calendar .= "<th  class='header'>$day</th>";
        
    } 
 $row=0;
    $calendar .= " 
    </tr>";
 $query = "SELECT name FROM rooms  ";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $user_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        
        foreach ($result as $val) {
            $calendar .="<tr>";
           $calendar .= "<td  class='empty'>$val[name]</td>";
               foreach($timeslots  as $rows) {
                $row++;
                  $calendar.="<td>
                  
     <input type='checkbox' class='btn-check' name='room' id='box$row' autocomplete='off' value='box$row'>
                                    <label class='btn btn-outline-success'  style='border-radius: 5px;' for='box$row'>Book</label>
           
           </td>";
               }
   

          
        }
       $calendar .= " 
    </tr>";
        }
  
  
     
     
    $calendar .= "</tr>";
    
    $calendar .= "</table>";
    return $calendar;
}
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form action="" method="post">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Time Slot</label>
                                    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" id="timeslot" name="timeslot">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Name</label>
                                    <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  "disabled>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group;>
                                    <label for="">Email</label>
                                    <input required type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  "disabled>
                                </div>
                                  <div class="form-group;>
                                    <label for="">Room</label>
                                    <input required type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  "disabled>
                                </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**can u please help me , thank u**

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It only runs when you make a page request, and is done and gone by the time the page starts to render in a browser. If you want to do something on a webpage that's running in a user's browser, that's purely a JS thing, so [(re)search how to do this](/help/how-to-ask) using JS instead of trying to figure out how to make PHP do this: it can't, it has no idea what a web page is, it's a network request handler that generates the _source code_ for a webpage.

Comment: If the submit button sends the data to the server via post/get, then you can echo the data in the modal HTML. If it doesn't, you will need to utilize javascript. From what you have shown and described, there isn't enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @imvain2 thank u for responding, for more information i want to show the timing and the room number that the user picked. the time is <th> and the room is <td> i want a way to retrieve it  since they are generated from foreach loop